# excel copy from one sheet and replace value while pasting

Tags: excel, replace, copy

I have a spreadsheet and whenever I make changes I have to make it in 6 different sheets. I want to create a template sheet so that when I make change in the template thats reflected in all 6 in same go. 
For example I will mention xxMGMT01 in the template sheet that should reflect as KKMGMT01 in first, LLMGMT01 in second and so on. Is there a formula that I can paste so that the 6 sheets copy the value from template and each sheet replaces the xx to the correct prefix?
I would prefer having a formula rather than a vba code

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer -
http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/substitute-function-HP010342927.aspx
using Substitute function